# Using regex to fetch a value

Tags: regex, perl, tcl

I have a string:

```
set a "ODUCTP-1-1-1-2P1"
regexp {.*?\-(.*)} $a match sub
```

I expect the value of sub to be 1-1-1-2P1

But I'm getting empty string. Can any one tell me how to properly use the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "ODUCTP-1-1-1-2P1";
$str =~ s/^.*?-//;
print $str;
```

or:

```
$str =~ /^.*?-(.*)$/;
print $1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the non-greediness of the `.*?` is leaking over to the `.*` later on, which is a feature of the RE engine being used (automata-theoretic instead of stack-based).

The simplest fix is to write the regular expression differently. 
Because Tcl has unanchored regular expressions (by default) and starts matches as soon as it can, a greedy match from the first `-` to the end of the string is perfect (with `sub` being assigned everything after the `-`). That's a very simple RE: `-(.*)`. To use that, you do this:

```
regexp -- {-(.*)} $a match sub
```

Note the `--`; it's needed here because the regular expression starts with a `-` symbol and is otherwise confused as weird (and unsupported) option. Apart from that one niggle, it's all entirely straight-forward.